# Something wrong happens between POST request and server

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I have this code in my static HTML page:

```
$(".js-submitbutton").click(function(){
    var title = $("#title").val();
    var subtitle = $("#subtitle").val();
    var imageurl = $("#imageurl").val();
    var telephone = $("#telephone").val();
    var address = $("#address").val();
    var category = $("#category").val();
    var keywords = $("#keywords").val();
    var website = $("website").val();
    var listofkeywords = keywords.split(',');
    var data = {
      title: title,
      subtitle: subtitle,
      image_url: imageurl,
      telephone: telephone,
      address: address,
      category: category,
      keywordslist: listofkeywords,
      website: website
    };
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "https://kakaobot.herokuapp.com/api_v1",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: data,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
      }
    })
 })
```

And on server, managing the POST request:

```
db.title = req.body.title;
db.subtitle = req.body.subtitle;
db.image_url = req.body.image_url;
db.telephone = req.body.telephone;
db.address = req.body.address;
db.category = req.body.category;
db.keywords = req.body.keywordslist;
db.save()
```

The problem is that when I press .js-submitbutton at HTML page, it collects data and sends correct JSON to the server, but in server logs, **keywordslist** is shown as **keywordslist[]**, which makes me impossible to save it to the database. 
Of course, I can always change the server code to accept **keywordslist[]**, but I don't want to do that unless there is no other choice. 
Thank you very much for helping, SO community, I really appreciate that.

Comment: Then don't use split, just set listofkeywords = keywords;

Comment: Add this -  data: JSON.stringify(data),

Comment: Wait.. you're trusting the keys sent by the user without looking at them first?   That sounds like loads of trouble or a crappy ORM.  Generally, if your incoming keys mismatch what you need to serialize into the database... you just mutate the object first.  `db.keywords = req.body.keywordslist[].join(',');`

Comment: Or, as I think about it.... don't bother to split it on the client side at all.  It appears that you're just going to have to join it back up before it goes into the DB unless you've got a relationship table that I'm not seeing in your declarations.

Comment: @JesperHøjer, thank you. I used split in server's code and everything went great. @Marcus H, this makes my data look like crap and that means more code on server's side. @John Green, I know it's very hackable, but it's a local solution used only by me for DB population and nobody else would see it. And the model I use in my DB is `{ 'keywords': ['keyword1', 'keyword2']`, so it's not an option to hardcode **keywordslist[]**, I mentioned that before. Yes, now I understand that every data manipulation should be on server side, not on clients. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to post my comment as the answer.

Change on the client side:

```
var listofkeywords = keywords.split(',');
```

to:

```
var listofkeywords = keywords;
```

Comment: And as additional hint - add whole logic on the server-side code.